# Focus or open a folder?

Tags: function, text, autoit, targeting

I've run into a few issues with this script:

```
If WinExists ("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]", "Address: C:\Users\Dad\Downloads") Then
    WinActivate ("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]", "Address: C:\Users\Dad\Downloads")
Else
    Run("Explorer.exe" & "C:\Users\Dad\Downloads")
Endif
```

1. If I have a subdirectory of *Downloads* open, like *C:\Users\Dad\Downloads\Pictures*, it will focus that window rather than continuing to the **Else** statement.
2. If there are no Windows Explorer windows open, the system just beeps at me, and the script closes.  I picked up my code in the answers here: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/30600-open-folder-with-autoit/ .

I tried to tag this for the `Run()` function and `text` parameter.

Comment: If " & " is removed, 2. is resolved.

Comment: For some reason, removing " & " also resolved 1.  So, I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, neither of the 2 unwanted behaviors occur with the following code:

```
If WinExists ("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]", "Address: C:\Users\Dad\Downloads") Then
    WinActivate ("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]", "Address: C:\Users\Dad\Downloads")
Else
    Run("Explorer.exe C:\Users\Dad\Downloads") #this line was changed.
Endif
```

Comment: The problem is that you missed a whitespace when you concatenate the two strings "Explorer.exe" and "C:\Users\Dad\Downloads" as you did in your question. Basically you tried to run this command: `Explorer.exeC:\Users\Dad\Downloads`. This just can't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of what you want to do. Basically your code is matching a sub string of the directory you are looking for. That is way it is activating windows with the same subdirectory.

```
FindorOpenExporer("C:\Users\Dad\Downloads")

Func FindorOpenExporer($sPath)
    Local $aWinList = WinList("[CLASS:CabinetWClass]")

    ;if no Exporer windows are found
    If IsArray($aWinList) = False Then
        StartEplorer($sPath)
        Return 0
    EndIf

    ;if explorer windows are found
    For $i = 1 To UBound($aWinList) - 1
        $sWinText = WinGetText($aWinList[$i][1])

        ;activates the window and returns the window handle if it is found
        If StringInStr($sWinText, "Address: " & $sPath) Then
            WinActivate($aWinList[$i][1])

            ;returns the window handle
            Return $aWinList[$i][1]
        EndIf
    Next

    StartEplorer($sPath)
EndFunc   ;==>FindorOpenExporer

Func StartEplorer($sPath)
    Run("Explorer.exe " & $sPath)
EndFunc   ;==>StartEplorer
```